# How to create a Gzip archive in java, from strings?

Tags: java, compression, zip, gzip

I have 3 strings, each one of them representing a `txt` file content, not loaded from the computer, but generated by `Java`.

```
String firstFileCon = "firstContent"; //File in .gz: 1.txt
String secondFileCon = "secondContent"; //File in .gz: 2.txt
String thirdFileCon = "thirdContent"; //File in .gz: 3.txt
```

How do I create a `GZIP` file, with the three files in it, and save the compressed file to the disc?

Comment: Do the strings hold filenames of files you want to compress or do you want to compress the strings themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a zip-file named *output.zip* that contains the files *1.txt*, *2.txt* and *3.txt* with their content string, try the following:

```
Map<String, String> entries = new HashMap<String, String>();
entries.put("firstContent", "1.txt");
entries.put("secondContent", "2.txt");
entries.put("thirdContent", "3.txt");

FileOutputStream fos = null;
ZipOutputStream zos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream("output.zip");

    zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntry : entries.entrySet()) {
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(mapEntry.getValue()); // create a new zip file entry with name, e.g. "1.txt"
        entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.DEFLATED); // set the compression method
        zos.putNextEntry(entry); // add the ZipEntry to the ZipOutputStream
        zos.write(mapEntry.getKey().getBytes()); // write the ZipEntry content
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // do something
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do something
} finally {
    if (zos != null) {
        zos.close();
    }
}
```

See [Creating ZIP and JAR files](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/creating_zip_and_jar_files) for more information, in particular the chapter *Compressing Files*.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, `GZIP` is only used for compressing single files (hence why `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` only really supports a single entry).

For multiple files I'd recommend using a format designed for multiple files (like zip).  `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream` provides just that.  If, for some reason, you really want the end result to be a `GZIP`, you could always create a `ZIP` file which contains all your 3 files and then GZIP that.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you want to store just the text or actual individual files.  I don't think you can store multiple files in a GZIP without first TARing.  Here is an example for storing a string to GZIP though.  Maybe it will help you along:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GZIPOutputStream gos = null;

    try {
        String str = "some string here...";
        File myGzipFile = new File("myFile.gzip");

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        gos = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myGzipFile));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            gos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { gos.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```